# create xml nodes using loop, coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I was wondering if one could create xml objects with a loop. For example:

```
<cfset LOCAL.terminator = "|">
<cfxml variable="XML_file_format">
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <cfoutput><cfloop list='fieldList' item="element" index='i'  delimiters=','>
            <FIELD ID="#i#" TERMINATOR="#LOCAL.terminator#" xsi:type="CharTerm"/>
            <cfif i EQ listLen(fieldList) - 1>  
                <cfbreak>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
        <FIELD ID="#listLen(fieldList)#" TERMINATOR="\r\n" xsi:type="CharTerm"/>
    </cfoutput></RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <cfoutput><cfloop list='fieldList' item="element" index='i' delimiters=','>
            <COLUMN NAME="#element#" SOURCE="#i#" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput></ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
</cfxml>
```

But When I do something like this, I just get 1 FIELD and 1 COLUMN. Is it possible to do a loop like this? Is there another way to do this? This is in ColdFusion btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your cfloops, you are looping over the string "fieldList" not the variable "#fieldList#". Coldfusion sees "fieldList" as a list with 1 element, so a single loop iteration.

Also I don't believe you need the cfoutput tags inside the cfxml tag.